# Image width issue while overriding

Tags: css

I am working with woo-commerce and i have small images for the product and i want to show the images in middle of the div but the problem is woo-commerce css use the width = 100% how can i override that and show the actual image

Woo-commerce CSS

```
.woocommerce div.product div.images img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

`.woocommerce div.product div.images box width is 300px`

And my image size is 200px show when i display the image it show me 300px size but i want to show it in 200px size.

I have try to override the css in my custom.css like bellow.

```
.woocommerce div.product div.images img {
      width:auto;
}
```

Comment: Please show how you're trying to override it.

Comment: I will write css in my custom.css so it will not affect when i upgrade the woo-commerce. `.woocommerce div.product div.images img { width:auto }` but not woring

Comment: maybe try !important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your stylesheet is loaded first, which causes the initial style to overide your selector. Try this:

```
body.woocommerce div.product div.images img {
      width: auto;
      margin: auto;
}
```

The `body` addition is to make sure this rule overwrites the default css. The `margin: auto` (or `margin: 0 auto`) rule is to center the block image.

Comment: I have tried the same it show me the image in full width

Comment: What is the URL of that page?

Comment: Well it's working here. Screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9719519/2015-06-10/wc%20example.png Note that I inserted the `body.woocommerce div.product div.images img` rules manually, because I couldn't see your custom css rule. Make sure your custom css is being loaded.

Comment: Yes i have try in http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqjqWj its working I will set it on site now

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to center the image.

- On the parent container of the image, set `text-align: center`.
- On the image, set `width: auto` and `display: inline-block`.

```css
.img-contain{
  width:300px;
  text-align: center;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.img-contain img {
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.center-image {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-contain">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"
        class="center-image" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target these items more specifically by adding the `id` of your content area to the selector (in this case, `#main` or `#content`):

```css
.woocommerce #main .product .images img {
    width: auto;
}
```

`id`s have a higher "priority" than classes.